# Slide out navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, slide, navigationbar

How can I get a navigation bar slide out, when I scroll up a tableview and slide in, when i scroll down? (Like the Facebook App or a lot others)

Thanks.

André

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most easy solution available on internet is to use "SWRevealViewController" Class made by John-Lluch.

You can download the source from this page for free.

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Don't forget to copy the SWRevealViewController.h and SWRevealViewController.m files to your project folder.

He has included 3 well detailed examples.

Hope this helps. Adios'.